# Dynamic active class not working boostrap + jQuery + navbar.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

Sorry for asking a question that's been asked so much on here in the past, but I'm still stuck and hoping you can provide insight for a a beginner.

The code that I'm using.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.nav > li').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('ul.nav > li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');                
    });            
  });
</script> 
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Text</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/one.php">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="/two.php">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="/three.php">Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="/four.php">Four</a></li>
        <li><a href="/five.php">Five</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

All of this is the contents of my navbar.php file that is being included in the header.php file.

What am I doing wrong?

Also; I was under the impression that the point of bootstrap was so that we didn't have to write custom js/jquery. Shouldn't this kind of functionality be built in? Have I misunderstood the concept of Bootstrap?

Comment: what CSS does `active` class have?

Comment: everything is working very fine, `active` class is also reflecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, but remember each time you reload your page, the settings will be removed and the whole menu will be reset

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.nav > li').click(function (e) {
        var $currentElement = $(this);

        e.preventDefault();
        $currentElement.siblings().removeClass('active');
        $currentElement.addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary fault on your code is that when ever the link is clicked the page is redirected to another php page so the effect of javascript click event will be overrides.

There are two possible solutions for this scenario:-

- Implement a server side solution by adding class active to the corresponding anchor tag for that page and is the simplest solution
- Implement a javascript method that read current url and perform a match with the anchor tag and make anchor tag  that matches to active.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with default bootstrap see the excerpt from their [documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/#tab):

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab" aria-controls="messages">Messages</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings">Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>

$(function () {
    $('#myTab').tab()
});
```

Comment: Not sure if I just don't understand the tab functionality, but the code provided in the documentation does not help with active pages.

Comment: You do need to include the bootstrap javascript file(s) including jquery. you just add the `[data-toggle="tab"]` attribute. Activate using the function mentioned above. You can listen to the lifecycle events to do certain actions after clicked. `$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
  e.target // newly activated tab
  e.relatedTarget // previous active tab
})`